# Can I run Apache2 as my user on my Ubuntu for development purposes?

Tags: server, root, mysql, php, apache2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)
>   [Should I as a developer use var/www in conjuction with apache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86016/should-i-as-a-developer-use-var-www-in-conjuction-with-apache)

I've gone and re-installed Ubuntu recently and I'm going thru the process of re-setup/install of some things. One is to setup Apache2, MySQL, etc, which is working correctly now.

I'm wondering if I should work my PHP/MySQL projects out of the /var/www/ directory for development purposes; or if I should create symnlinks over to my users directory; or perhaps I should just change Apache2 to run as the same user as me.

I'm the only user on this computer. Any suggestions?
Thanks, Jeff

Comment: related? http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-add-files-to-var-www/20114#20114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add yourself to the www-data group and then use /var/www with no issues `sudo adduser USERNAME www-data`